# Cookies not sent to the browser

Tags: laravel-5, session-cookies

I've upgraded laravel 5.5 to laravel 5.6 and suddenly i don't have a session cookie anymore. When i checkout the branch of laravel 5.5 cookies work.

When i login on our custom login controller and i dump the result of sendLoginResponse from the default AuthenticatesUsers trait this is the response:

[image: Response after login]

As you can see, nothing about cookies. So where is my cookie :)?
I also did take a look at my browsers cookies, but there are no cookies (Chrome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this issue seemed using another php version. I updated my php installation to the latest php at that moment and that was PHP 7.1.30.